# Change specific value in Dynamic nested array with parent and children structure PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, nested

I have a dynamic nested array structure with unique id and name, need to change value of name for a specific id given.

I have a dynamic nested array with structure
`

```
$array = [
    [
        "id" => "31350880",
        "name" => "HOD",
        "children" => [
            [
                "id" => "57f94cd7",
                "parent_id" => "31350880",
                "name" => "New HOD",
                "children" => [
                    [
                        "id" => "e7f1c88b",
                        "parent_id" => "57f94cd7",
                        "name" => "Gold",
                        "children" => [
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id" => "45881fa8",
        "name" => "Pictures",
        "children" => [
            [
                "id" => "770e6e20",
                "parent_id" => "45881fa8",
                "name" => "New Picture",
                "children" => [
                    [
                        "id" => "a403a8fa",
                        "parent_id" => "770e6e20",
                        "name" => "Silver",
                        "children" => [
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

`

For a given ID(unique) , need to find it from array and change the name from that node to a specific name.

for example : $id = ''770e6e20' which is a child of parent node with name "Pictures", need to find child node with specific id and change its name and retrieve the full array in its initial structure ?

Comment: You could envisage using a recursive function to cycle through the source array until it finds a match (`id`). You could then change `name` or manipulate the array anyway you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive function that gets a `reference` of your array, the `id` of the item and the new `name` to be assigned, and performs in place modification:

```
function modify_element_name(&$arr, $id, $name){
    foreach($arr as $index => $item){
        if($item['id'] === $id){
            $arr[$index]['name'] = $name;
            
        }
        else {
            if(count($item['children']) > 0){
                modify_element_name($arr[$index]['children'], $id, $name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling it as below:

```
modify_element_name($array, '770e6e20', 'New Picture Modified');
```

Will modify the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 31350880
            [name] => HOD
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 57f94cd7
                            [parent_id] => 31350880
                            [name] => New HOD
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => e7f1c88b
                                            [parent_id] => 57f94cd7
                                            [name] => Gold
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 45881fa8
            [name] => Pictures
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 770e6e20
                            [parent_id] => 45881fa8
                            [name] => New Picture Modified
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => a403a8fa
                                            [parent_id] => 770e6e20
                                            [name] => Silver
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```